# Using Javascript Modules in a SPA

Tags: javascript, module

To avoid using global variables, I would like to rebuild my SPA and use JavaScript modules instead.

My main Javascript file, which I included in the index.html, has a similar structure to this file: https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/main/history-api/script.js

I have outsourced the various subpages of my SPA as a module. Now it looks something like this:

script.js

```
import { showMap } from "./map.js"

function displayContent() {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search)
  switch (true) {
    ...
    case searchParams.has("map"): showMap(); break;
    case searchParams.has("page"): showPage(); break;
    ...
  }
}
```

map.js

```
function showMap() {
  ...
  path.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams()
    searchParams.set("page", "newPage")
    const state = { page_id: 2 };
    displayContent();
    history.pushState(state, "", "?" + searchParams);
  });
  ...
}

export default showMap
```

However, when I click on the button I always get the error message

> ReferenceError displayContent is not defined

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to turn around and import the displayContent as a module in map.js and page.js, then I get the message

> ReferenceError showMap is not defined
> ReferenceError showPage is not defined

Comment: displayContent is defined outside the map.js module, it's expected. and we don't have your try when you import displayContent into map.js

Comment: You should export the `displayContent` function in the file it is defined, and `import` it in the file where you want to use it.

Comment: I've already tried it that way. But then displayContent doesn't know about the showMap and showPage functions

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call a function `displayContent` inside of itself.
Either map.js needs to have it's own definition of a function called `displayContent` or you need to pass the reference/import it into map.js.

Additionally,
map.js is calling a function defined in its calling code.

If you want map.js to be a self contained module, I suggest passing the function into the map.

e.g.

```
function showMap(displayContent) {
  ...
  path.addEventListener("click", function() {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams()
    searchParams.set("page", "newPage")
    const state = { page_id: 2 };
    displayContent();
    history.pushState(state, "", "?" + searchParams);
  });
  ...
}

export default showMap
```